# python scrapy xpath text() failed extract text with <b />

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am using scrapy shell and trying to get the text part of the following element

```
<div class="CCCCC">AAA<br />BBB<br />CCC<br />DDD</div>
```

By using

```
response.xpath('//div [@class="CCCCC"]')[0].extract()
```

I got a whole element includes tags,

```
<div class="CCCCC">AAA<br>BBB<br>CCC<br>DDD</div>
```

but using

```
response.xpath('//div [@class="CCCCC"]/text()')[0].extract()
```

I got only `'AAA'` instead of `'AAA<br>BBB<br>CCC<br>DDD'`that I expected.

Is the behavior of text() correct ?

Comment: Why would You expect that? `<br>` is a tag, so it makes perfect sense that You got only `AAA`.

Comment: `text()` is a node test and selects nodes that are text nodes. There are 4 text nodes that are children of that `<div class="CCCCC">`: "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD". `'AAA<br>BBB<br>CCC<br>DDD'` is what innerHTML or something would get you. But you cannot get that from XPath alone.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is correct.

```
response.xpath('//div [@class="CCCCC"]/text()')
```

will give `[AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD]` as a **list** but your code is

`response.xpath('//div [@class="CCCCC"]/text()')[0].extract()`

Note that you ask the **first** element of the with `[0]`. That's why you only get `AAA`.

If you remove the `[0]` you will have all the four elements.

Answer (score 0):

Please avoid using "[0].extract()" in scrapy,it may lead to list index out of error.

Please use `response.xpath('//div [@class="CCCCC"]/text()').extract_first()`,it will save you ,if there is no first element

for further details check here [Scrapy Selector](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html)